# What is a list of synonyms for "collectively exhaustive cases"?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, optimization

I need a synonym for the term "collectively exhaustive cases". I know that "collectively exhaustive events" is correct to say, but I am told that "collectively exhaustive cases" is questionable and a bit unclear. I suppose I could say "cases inclusive of all possibilities" instead...

What is a list of more synonyms for "collectively exhaustive cases" / "cases inclusive of all possibilities"?

Thank you.

Comment: What about "all possible cases"? It would help if you said why "collectively exhaustive cases" is questionable, so we would know what concern is to be avoided. Also, the actual sentence in which this is to be used probably makes a significant difference in what word combinations fit well.

Comment: Or just "all cases."  (They're not cases if they're not possible.)

Comment: Someone told me "collectively exhaustive cases" is questionable English... does it sound ok to you, though?

Just to make sure, what I mean by collectively exhaustive cases is that they are cases such at at least one of them must occur. For instance, the cases: (1) my calculator is in my bag and (2) my calculator is not in my bag, are collectively exhaustive (one of them must be true; there is absolutely no other option).

Is "collectively exhaustive" correct?